# WordPress Slider Occasionally Breaks

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble with the slider breaking on a WordPress site.  When the site load sometimes the WordPress loops breaks and the end div for the slider ends up below a few other elements on the page, making those elements part of the slider. I've tried disabling JavaScript but the problem still exist.

```
<div class="slidermap" id="map"></div>


<?php   

    $counter = 0; 

?>



<?php if ($posts->have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>



        <?php

        include 'variables.php';

        $arr_sliderimages = get_gallery_images();

        $resized_infowindowimage = aq_resize($arr_sliderimages[0], 50, 50, true);

        ?>                      



        <?php 

        if ($map) {

        $themap = $map;

        } else {

        $themap = $address . " " . $citystatezip;

        }

        $array_mapinfo[$counter] = array(0 =>$themap, 1=>$address, 2=>$citystatezip, 3=>$resized_infowindowimage, 4=>$price, 5=>get_permalink(), 6=>get_the_title());

        $counter++;

    ?>



<?php endwhile ?>



<?php else : ?>



<?php endif; ?>



<?php include TEMPLATEPATH .'/js/resultsmap.php'; ?>
```

```
    <div class="images"> 

    <?php 

    $count = 1;

    if ($posts->have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

    <?php include 'variables.php'; 

    $content = get_the_content();

    ?>



    <?php if($count != 1) { 

        $hide = "style='display: none;'";

    } ?>



     <div class="slide"><!-- slide --> 



            <?php if ($slider == "Recent Listings") { ?>

            <div class="slidertext" <?php echo $hide; ?>>

                <div class="slidertext_inner">



                    <h2 class="citystatezip"><?php echo $locname ?></h2>



                    <p class="excerpt_text">

                    <?php echo substr($content, 0, 150) . "..." ?>

                    </p>

                    <?php /*

                    <ul>


                    <?php if ($cr == "Residential") { ?>



                    <li class="bedsbaths"><?php echo get_option('wp_bedrooms_text').": ".$beds. " &bull; " . get_option('wp_bathrooms_text').": ". $baths ?></li>

                    <?php } ?>



                    <li class="price"><?php include 'price.php'; ?></li>

                    </ul> */ ?>

                    <div class="button_border"><a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_option('wp_read_more_text') ?></a></div>

                </div><!-- end inner -->

            </div><!-- end slidertext -->

            <?php } ?>


            <div class="sliderimage">

                <?php $arr_sliderimages = get_gallery_images();





                if ($slider == "Recent Listings") {

                    $w = 685;

                    } else {

                    $w = 720;

                    }



                $resized = aq_resize($arr_sliderimages[0], $w, 320, true);

                ?>



                <?php include 'bannerslarge.php'; ?>



            <?php if($condoshopdate) { 

            $condoshopdate2 = strtotime($condoshopdate);

            $today = strtotime(Date("F d, Y"));

            if ($today <= $condoshopdate2) {

                echo "<div class='condoshopbanner'><div class='condoshopdatetime'>".$condoshopdate.", ".$condoshoptime."</div></div>";

            } 

            } ?>    

                <?php if ($slider == "Recent Listings") { ?>

                <?php } else { ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $slideshow_url; ?>"><img alt="" class="sliderborder" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/sliderborder.png" /></a>

                <?php } ?>



                <?php if ($slider == "Recent Listings") { ?>

                <div class="faderight"></div>

                <?php } ?>



                <img width="<?php echo $w ?>" height="320" alt="" src="<?php echo $resized ?>" />

            </div><!-- end sliderimage -->  



    </div> <!-- end slide -->

    <?php $count++ ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p><strong>There are no items to display.  You need to add at least one Property Listing post.</strong></p>



    <?php endif; 

    wp_reset_query(); ?> 

    </div><!-- end images -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was how the excerpts was being generated by this line of code .  The theme creator bypass just using the_excerpt() for some reason. Thanks!